# Mongo array limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to insert an object in Mongo using the native node library. I have an object that has an array property that has 1620 objects. In the documentation it says mongo has support for nesting up to 100 levels which I'm not running into. The objects in the array are just objects, they don't have any arrays. The size of the total document with all the items is only 456Kb. If I limit the array to 788 objects they do get saved in the database but it crashses the app. Am I running into a problem with the native mongo library for node? Missing a setting for database?

```
var droplist = convertOptionList(data);

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  if(err) {console.log('error'); throw err;}

  var collection = db.collection('droplist');

  collection.insert(droplist, function(err, objects) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('error');
      throw err;
    }
    //never see this message. app crashes but with fewer items the query passes
    console.log("A-Ok");
  });
  db.close();
});
```

**Update**

Working version of the code. Slight change to move the db.close() inside of the callback for insert and preventing the db.close to be called before the objects have all been inserted.

```
var droplist = convertOptionList(data);

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
  if(err) {console.log('error'); throw err;}

  var collection = db.collection('droplist');

  collection.insert(droplist, function(err, objects) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('error');
      throw err;
    }
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: Should've clarified. I was running my app with supervisor and I saw the app crashing and restarting when the query was executed so I didn't actually see an error message from Mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake. I put my db.close() outside of my callback so the connection was closing before the query could run/finish.  Moved my db.close() into the callback and everything works now.